# Invalid multicast interface

Tags: freebsd, pfsense

I am trying to use `ping` with specified interface with a command

```
ping -I re3 192.168.1.1
```

I know `re3` exists from `ifconfig`

```
re3: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=8209b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,WOL_MAGIC,LINKSTATE>
        ether e8:de:27:01:7f:e7
        inet6 fe80::eade:27ff:fe01:7fe7%re3 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x4
        inet 192.168.1.2 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        media: Ethernet autoselect (100baseTX <full-duplex>)
        status: active
```

Unfortunately I can't ping it's gateway:

```
$/root: ping -I re3 192.168.1.1
ping: invalid multicast interface: `re3'
```

What that mean?

**UPDATE**

```
$arp 192.168.1.1
? (192.168.1.1) at (incomplete) on re3 expired [ethernet]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not much experience in freebsd system, as far as i know for ping try:

```
ping -S 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1
```

As for ***arp***

- If arp cant fetch mac address of your gateway then freebsd server
  lost it's connectivity with the gateway.
- Check whether gateway of your server is UP/RUNNING, and also check
  the physical connectivty of both.

Answer (score 8):

On FreeBSD and macos the `-I` flag does not behave as one would expect from Linux. If you check the man page carefully, you'll see:

> ```
>  -I iface
>         Source multicast packets with the given interface **address**.
> ```

[emphasis mine]

So the `-I` flag actually expects an address, not an interface. You can confirm with something like:

```
$ ping -I 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1
```

But unless your target IP address is a multicast address this will still fail.

To get the behaviour we all know and expect from `traceroute` and Linux, use the `-S` flag instead and specify the IP address of the interface you want to use:

```
$ ping -S 192.168.1.2 192.168.1.1
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) from 192.168.1.20: 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.1.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=5.956 ms
```